# How do I find number of values in array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array and am trying to extract the vlaues. I have tried to find the length of the array, but as the array isnt always full the .length doesnt work for me. How do i work out how many values are stored in the array?

Heres the code;
int length = numbers.Length;

I have created the array in the main section of the code, I am trying to make a function that can get the values out of the code using a for loop. E.G
int number(i) = numbers[i]

so that the variable number[i] will become number0, and then assigned the value in the first row of the array

Comment: Can you please show your full relevant code? By the way, the right property is `.Length` not `.length`.

Comment: what's the value's type

Comment: An array is always full. I.e. initializing an array of ints yields an array filled with zero's.

Comment: An array of what?  What is your definition of "isn't always full"?  Show the code please.

Comment: by "isnt always full" i mean that I have sized array numbers to be 20, and someetimes only 10 values are assigned into it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use array which is not always full, then you definitely should use [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of array, because list can contain variable number of items. With array you never can tell if default value (zero for integer) was assigned to array item, or item was not assigned at all. Getting list items count will look like [`list.Count`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Of course, you can get number of array items which have non-default value (but see above why it might be not good approach):

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 0, 1, 5 };
int count = array.Count(i => i != default(int)); // 4
```

Answer (score 0):

try [foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ts69ce3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) you do not need the length. Here is code:

```
int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
foreach (int element in numbers)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(element);
}
```